# VGG Face Descriptor in python with caffe

Tags: python, matlab, deep-learning, caffe, vgg-net

I want implement [VGG Face Descriptor](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/vgg_face/) in python. But I keep getting an error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "numpy.ndarray") to list

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 
import caffe
img = cv2.imread("ak.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
net = caffe.Net("VGG_FACE_deploy.prototxt","VGG_FACE.caffemodel",  caffe.TEST)
print net.forward(img)
```

Can you help me ?

**UPDATE 1**

This working code is example in matlab

```
%  Copyright (c) 2015, Omkar M. Parkhi
%  All rights reserved.
img = imread('ak.png');
img = single(img);

    Img = [129.1863,104.7624,93.5940] ;

img = cat(3,img(:,:,1)-averageImage(1),...
    img(:,:,2)-averageImage(2),...
    img(:,:,3)-averageImage(3));

img = img(:, :, [3, 2, 1]); % convert from RGB to BGR
img = permute(img, [2, 1, 3]); % permute width and height

model = 'VGG_FACE_16_deploy.prototxt';
weights = 'VGG_FACE.caffemodel';
caffe.set_mode_cpu();
net = caffe.Net(model, weights, 'test'); % create net and load weights

res = net.forward({img});
prob = res{1};

caffe_ft = net.blobs('fc7').get_data();
```

Comment: why aren't you using `caffe.io.load_image`?

Comment: If i try `caffe.io.load_image` s i get same error `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "numpy.ndarray") to list`. If I try passing a single element list to method i get error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: try `net.forward_all` instead of `forward`.

Comment: same error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: can you get a stack trace to show what line of code exactly causes this error?

Comment: The error is caused on line 173 in this file - [link](http://pastebin.com/3kZ4hww6) and this is the image [link](http://pastebin.com/SQ8HnVTU)

Comment: line 173 is a comment. can you please copy the line?

Comment: sorry.  `all_outs = {out: [] for out in set(self.outputs + (blobs or []))}` . Line 174.

Comment: can you post `'VGG_FACE_16_deploy.prototxt'` please?

Comment: There is `VGG_FACE_16_deploy.prototxt` -  [link](http://pastebin.com/z6NE8CCm)

Comment: can you please try `net.forward_all(data=[img])`?

Comment: Ok. This is looking better. When I try `net.forward_all(data = [img])` I get error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'` (caused by line 101). But when i try `net.forward_all(data = img)` i get error `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,224,3) into shape (1,3,224,224)` (caused by line 176 and then 103). This maybe resolve UPDATE 1 in my post but i dont know synatx of matlab language. Do you know what happen with image from read image to call `res = net.forward({img});`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use python interface you need to transform the input image before feeding it to the net

```
img = caffe.io.load_image( "ak.png" )
img = img[:,:,::-1]*255.0 # convert RGB->BGR
avg = np.array([93.5940, 104.7624, 129.1863])  # BGR mean values
img = img - avg # subtract mean (numpy takes care of dimensions :)
```

Now `img` is `H`-by-`W`-by-3 numpy array.
Caffe expects its inputs as 4D: batch_index `x` channel `x` width `x` height.
Therefore you need to `transpose` the input and add a singleton dimension to represent the "batch_index" leading dimension

```
img = img.transpose((2,0,1)) 
img = img[None,:] # add singleton dimension
```

Now you can run the forward pass

```
out = net.forward_all( data = img )
```

Comment: where does this average come from?

Comment: @maxou it was part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV reads in BGR and scaled to 255 format by default, so:

```
img = cv2.imread('ak.png')
avg = np.array([93.5940,104.7624,129.1863]) # BGR mean from VGG
img -= avg # subtract mean
img = img.transpose((2,0,1)) # to match image input dimension: 3x224x224
img = img[None,:] # add singleton dimension to match batch dimension
out = net.forward_all(data = img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a single element list to the method.

```
net.forward ([img])
```

Comment: Whetn i try it i get this error: 

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'